# .NET WinForms application not releasing components?

Tags: c#, .net, components, dispose

I'm working with a .NET 2.0 WinForms application in C#.

I noticed something that I thought to be strange during the tear down of my application.  In the designer generated dispose method:

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

I'm seeing a situation where it is passing in `disposing = false` parameter when `components` does indeed contain some items.  This leads me to believe that these resources are not getting disposed correctly/released because `components.Dispose();` is not getting called.  Is this ever desired behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: Was that situation called from the Garbage Collector (Finalizer/Destructor)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `disposing` parameter will be passed as false if `Dispose(bool)` is being called from the finalizer. Typically this occurs when `Dispose()` hasn't been called.

---

The `Dispose(bool)` method isn't actually part of IDisposable; it's used by both `IDisposable.Dispose()` and by `Object.Finalize()`.  The convention is that `IDisposable.Dispose()` will call `Dispose(true)` and `Object.Finalize()` will call `Dipose(false)`.

Comment: Is it ever implicitly called with true?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your class needs to dispose of unmanaged resources and therefor implements a finalizer as well?

Something like this:

```
   ~MyForm()
    {
       this.Dispose(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If `Dispose(false)` is called during finalization that is fine by itself. If the Form is being finalized the contained Controls will also be on the finalization queue and calling Dispose() on them is at least superfluous.

But the fact that a Form is being finalized means that no deterministic Dispose() was called on it, and that by itself should be investigated. Unless this happens when the App is closing, as you state. Then it is harmless.

Comment: The form that I was investigating was actually a dialog, so the application as a whole was still running after this form closed. As a result, components were never collected because Dispose(false) would be called whenever the garbage collector got around to making a pass to this dialog form. I added an explicit call to Form.Dispose() after the dialog form gets closed. Added some break points, and low and behold, Dispose(true) was called and the components (tooltips/timers) were removed correctly. Thanks for explanation!